# Error occuriring with call to user authenticated http trigger

Tags: azure, authentication, jwt, azure-functions

I am using Azure Functions v3

I am trying to use Authentication and I have set my function to User level security for its HttpTriggers

The logic below is called on the startup of my function

```cs
protected override void SetupAuthentication(
    IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var tokenOptions = configuration.GetSection("JwtIssuerOptions")
                    .Get<TokenConfiguration>();
                
    var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // The signing key must match!
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = tokenOptions.SecurityKey,
            // Validate the JWT Issuer (iss) claim
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,
            // Validate the JWT Audience (aud) claim
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience,
            // Validate the token expiry
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            // If you want to allow a certain amount of clock drift, set that here:
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
                
    services.Configure<IdentityConfiguration>(configuration.GetSection("IdentityConfiguration"));
    services.AddScoped<CustomJwtBearerEvents>();
    
    services
        .AddAuthentication(o =>
         {
              o.DefaultForbidScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
              o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
         {
              options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
              options.EventsType = typeof(CustomJwtBearerEvents);
         });
    
    }
```

When I call the function externally I get the error

```
No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'WebJobsAuthLevel'.
```

The registered schemes are: Bearer. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddSomeAuthHandler?.

What have I missed?

I need to mimic the same convention as web apps

```cs
[FunctionName("GetPayments")]
public async Task<List<PaymentDto>> GetPaymentsAsync(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.User, "post", Route = "payments/get-payments")]
     HttpRequest req, 
     ILogger log)
{
    var data = await req.ReadAsStringAsync();
            
    //THis is where I have my logic which I only want to be able to access if the user has permissions
}
```

I have seen the link below

https://damienbod.com/2020/09/24/securing-azure-functions-using-azure-ad-jwt-bearer-token-authentication-for-user-access-tokens/comment-page-1/?unapproved=127819&moderation-hash=3fdd04b596812933c4c32e8e8c8cf26a#comment-127819

It initially looked to be what I need, but I cant work out how to adapt it so that it just uses the identity token validation side

Any help would be appreciated

Paul

Comment: Hey Paul, any luck with that? I have a same issue with IS4

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorize

The latest version ensures all built-in authentication is in place before you add your own or extend the built-in ones. By the way JTW Bearer is already configured by the Functions runtime.

All you need to do is call in your method

```cs
services.AddFunctionsAuthentication();
services.AddFunctionsAuthorization();
```

and then chain whatever other schemes you need to configure after the `AddFunctionsAuthentication()` call. The resulting authentication builder is designed to handle modifications to the jwt bearer (`AddJwtBearer(options => ...`) and will not break telling you the `Bearer` scheme already exists.

This package also gives you the ability to use the `FunctionsAuthorize` attribute to handle granular authorization requirements for your HTTP functions. Here is a blog post with details: https://blog.darkloop.com/post/functionauthorize-for-azure-functions-v3